# Very different performance between two similar queries

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7

We are working on a view (multiple joins in this view). And I have these two queries:

- Query 1:

  ```
  select *
  from v_investment_planning_ticket v
                 where v.ticket_id in
                       (select ti.ticket_id from ticket_item ti where ti.status = 'SENT')
  order by v.period_created desc;
  ```
- Query 2:

  ```
  select *
  from v_investment_planning_ticket v
  where v.ticket_id in
        (select ti.ticket_id from ticket_item ti where ti.status = 'SENT')
    and (v.ticket_status in
         ('NEW', 'NOT_DEPOSIT_IN', 'CASH_NOT_ENOUGH', 'CASH_ENOUGH', 'EXPIRED_DEPOSIT', 'PENDING', 'PROCESSING',
          'EXPIRED', 'REJECTED', 'PARTIALLY_SUCCESSFUL', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED'))
  order by v.period_created desc;
  ```

I can say that the meaning of the second query is the same. But with the first one MySQL takes ~40 seconds each time to query it. And with the second one it only takes ~0.7 seconds. And the difference is I added one more condition in the 2nd query with ALL the ticket status values I have.

Please tell me why, when I do that, it's so different.

#### Additional details

- Query 1 EXPLAIN:

  ```json
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "<subquery2>",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": null,
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": null,
      "filtered": 100,
      "Extra": "Using temporary; Using filesort"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "tk",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ticket_investment_planning_id_fk,ticket_target_term_period_id_fk",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_len": "8",
      "ref": "<subquery2>.ticket_id",
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "Extra": null
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "p",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,investment_planning_target_id_fk",
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": 12133,
      "filtered": 0.01,
      "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "ttp",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": 5,
      "filtered": 20,
      "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "t",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_len": "8",
      "ref": "dgo_db.p.target_id",
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "select_type": "MATERIALIZED",
      "table": "ti",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": "ticket_item_ticket_id_fk",
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": 42797,
      "filtered": 14.29,
      "Extra": "Using where"
    }
  ]
  ```
- Query 2 EXPLAIN:

  ```json
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "ti",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": "ticket_item_ticket_id_fk",
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": 42797,
      "filtered": 14.29,
      "Extra": "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "tk",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ticket_investment_planning_id_fk,ticket_target_term_period_id_fk",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_len": "8",
      "ref": "dgo_db.ti.ticket_id",
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 50,
      "Extra": "Using where; End temporary"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "ttp",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
      "key": null,
      "key_len": null,
      "ref": null,
      "rows": 5,
      "filtered": 20,
      "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "p",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,investment_planning_target_id_fk",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_len": "8",
      "ref": "dgo_db.tk.investment_plan_id",
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "select_type": "SIMPLE",
      "table": "t",
      "partitions": null,
      "type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_len": "8",
      "ref": "dgo_db.p.target_id",
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "Extra": "Using index"
    }
  ]
  ```
- View `v_investment_planning_ticket`:

  ```
  select `p`.`id`                      AS `plan_id`,
         `p`.`customer_id`             AS `customer_id`,
         `p`.`customer_name`           AS `customer_name`,
         `p`.`custody_code`            AS `custody_code`,
         `p`.`account_no`              AS `account_no`,
         `p`.`tag_text`                AS `tag_text`,
         `p`.`target_id`               AS `target_id`,
         `p`.`target_name`             AS `target_name`,
         `p`.`business_line_id`        AS `business_line_id`,
         `p`.`business_line_name`      AS `business_line_name`,
         `p`.`business_line_code`      AS `business_line_code`,
         `p`.`product_key`             AS `product_key`,
         `p`.`target_portfolio`        AS `target_portfolio`,
         `p`.`target_attribute`        AS `target_attribute`,
         `p`.`careby_id`               AS `careby_id`,
         `p`.`careby_name`             AS `careby_name`,
         `p`.`department_id`           AS `department_id`,
         `p`.`department_name`         AS `department_name`,
         `p`.`execution_method`        AS `execution_method`,
         `p`.`creator`                 AS `creator`,
         `tk`.`id`                     AS `ticket_id`,
         `tk`.`status`                 AS `ticket_status`,
         `tk`.`total_amount`           AS `total_amount`,
         `tk`.`total_quantity`         AS `total_quantity`,
         `tk`.`total_located_amount`   AS `total_located_amount`,
         `tk`.`total_located_quantity` AS `total_located_quantity`,
         `tk`.`careby_id`              AS `ticket_careby_id`,
         `ttp`.`id`                    AS `period_id`,
         `ttp`.`name`                  AS `period_name`,
         `ttp`.`year`                  AS `period_year`,
         `ttp`.`start_time`            AS `period_start_time`,
         `ttp`.`end_time`              AS `period_end_time`,
         `ttp`.`created`               AS `period_created`
  from (((`investment_planning` `p` join `target` `t` on ((`p`.`target_id` = `t`.`id`))) join `ticket` `tk` on ((`p`.`id` = `tk`.`investment_plan_id`)))
           join `target_term_period` `ttp` on ((`ttp`.`id` = `tk`.`period_id`)));
  ```
- Table `ticket_item`:

  ```
  create table ticket_item
  (
      id                bigint unsigned auto_increment
          primary key,
      ticket_id         bigint unsigned                                                                            not null,
      status            enum ('PENDING', 'PROCESSING', 'SENT', 'FILLED', 'PARTIALLY_FILLED', 'FAILED', 'REJECTED') not null,
      error_description varchar(255)                                                                               null,
      trading_date      date                                                                                       null,
      sec_type          varchar(50)                                                                                null,
      trans_ref         varchar(50)                                                                                null,
      code_id           varchar(50)                                                                                null,
      symbol            varchar(50)                                                                                null,
      product_id        varchar(100)                                                                               null,
      product_code      varchar(50)                                                                                null,
      quantity          decimal(12, 3)                                                                             null,
      amount            decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
      located_quantity  decimal(12, 3)                                                                             null,
      located_amount    decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
      price             decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
      rate              decimal(6, 3)                                                                              null,
      created           datetime                                                                                   not null,
      modified          timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                                        null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      constraint ticket_item_ticket_id_fk
          foreign key (ticket_id) references ticket (id)
  );
  ```
- Table `ticket`:

  ```
  create table ticket
  (
      id                     bigint unsigned auto_increment
          primary key,
      code                   varchar(100)                                                                                                                                                                        not null,
      investment_plan_id     bigint unsigned                                                                                                                                                                     not null,
      status                 enum ('NEW', 'NOT_DEPOSIT_IN', 'CASH_NOT_ENOUGH', 'CASH_ENOUGH', 'EXPIRED_DEPOSIT', 'PENDING', 'PROCESSING', 'EXPIRED', 'REJECTED', 'PARTIALLY_SUCCESSFUL', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED') not null,
      total_quantity         decimal(12, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      null,
      total_amount           decimal(15, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      null,
      total_located_quantity decimal(12, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      null,
      total_located_amount   decimal(15, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      null,
      creator                varchar(100)                                                                                                                                                                        null,
      careby_id              varchar(100)                                                                                                                                                                        null,
      period_id              bigint unsigned                                                                                                                                                                     null,
      expired_time           datetime                                                                                                                                                                            null,
      careby_name            varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                        null,
      created                datetime                                                                                                                                                                            not null,
      modified               timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                                                                                                                                 null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      constraint ticket_investment_planning_id_fk
          foreign key (investment_plan_id) references investment_planning (id),
      constraint ticket_target_term_period_id_fk
          foreign key (period_id) references target_term_period (id)
  ```
- Table `target`:

  ```
  create table target
  (
      id               bigint unsigned auto_increment
          primary key,
      business_line_id bigint unsigned                                                      null,
      code             varchar(100)                                                         null,
      name             varchar(255)                                                         null,
      product_key      varchar(100)                                                         null,
      type             enum ('PORTFOLIO_REQUIRED', 'PORTFOLIO_EMPTY', 'PORTFOLIO_OPTIONAL') null,
      description      varchar(500)                                                         null,
      active           bit       default b'0'                                               null,
      creator          varchar(255)                                                         null,
      created          datetime                                                             null,
      modified         timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                  null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      constraint fk_target_businessLine
          foreign key (business_line_id) references business_line (id)
              on update cascade
  );
  ```
- Table `investment_planning`:

  ```
  create table investment_planning
  (
      id                 bigint unsigned auto_increment
          primary key,
      customer_id        varchar(100)                                                             null,
      customer_name      varchar(255)                                                             null,
      careby_id          varchar(100)                                                             null,
      careby_name        varchar(100)                                                             null,
      department_id      varchar(100)                                                             null,
      department_name    varchar(255)                                                             null,
      custody_code       varchar(500)                                                             null,
      account_no         varchar(50)                                                              null,
      tag_text           varchar(500)                                                             null,
      business_line_id   bigint unsigned                                                          null,
      business_line_code varchar(45)                                                              null,
      business_line_name varchar(255)                                                             null,
      product_key        varchar(45)                                                              null,
      target_id          bigint unsigned                                                          null,
      target_name        varchar(255)                                                             null,
      target_attribute   json                                                                     null,
      target_withdraw    json                                                                     null,
      target_portfolio   json                                                                     null,
      auto_execution     bit       default b'0'                                                   null,
      execution_method   enum ('AUTO', 'SEMI_AUTO', 'MANUAL')                                     null,
      status             enum ('PENDING', 'WAITING', 'ACTIVE', 'DEACTIVATE', 'EXPIRED', 'CANCEL') null,
      creator            varchar(100)                                                             null,
      editor             varchar(255)                                                             null,
      created            datetime                                                                 null,
      edited             datetime                                                                 null,
      modified           timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                      null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      constraint investment_planning_business_line_id_fk
          foreign key (business_line_id) references business_line (id),
      constraint investment_planning_target_id_fk
          foreign key (target_id) references target (id)
  );
  ```
- Table `target_term_period`:

  ```
  create table target_term_period
  (
      id         bigint unsigned auto_increment
          primary key,
      target_id  bigint unsigned                     not null,
      start_time datetime                            not null,
      end_time   datetime                            not null,
      name       varchar(50)                         not null,
      year       int                                 not null,
      created    datetime                            null,
      modified   timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      constraint target_term_period_target_id_start_time_end_time_uindex
          unique (target_id, start_time, end_time),
      constraint target_term_period_target_id_fk
          foreign key (target_id) references target (id)
  );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; change to a `JOIN`.

It may help to have these composite indexes:

```
ti:  (status, ticket_id)
ti:  (ticket_id, status)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know where to fix it bro. But I really wanna know why my query has one more condition and maybe this condition is very meaningless but it make the query become faster

Comment: @DucAnhPham - Apparently it tricked the Optimizer into using a better index.  (I don't see enough details to come up with a better answer than that.)

Comment: @DucAnhPham - toss all the parentheses after "from"; see if the `EXPLAIN` changes any.

Comment: Yeah I think my question is hard for explain because too much thing I need to provide. Thanks for your suggestion.